# Automatic wildcard subdomains on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

Currently I have several virtual hosts set up for individual subdomains. It would be a lot easier if I could tell Apache to automatically find the folder using a wildcard. For example, `hello.domain.com` would use the `/var/www/hello` directory as its `DocumentRoot`.

I would like to be able to define exceptions however, such as if I wanted `helloworld.domain.com` to point to `/var/www/helloworld/public` instead.

I've looked around but all of the examples seem to be doing something different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll be able to configure that behavior with something along these lines:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName catchall.domain.com
  ServerAlias *.domain.com
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName helloworld.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/helloworld/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks. Why `ServerName catchall.domain.com`? Why not just have `ServerAlias *.domain.com`?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh You need a `ServerName` in that vhost, but its name really doesn't matter - `ServerName a` would work just as well.

Comment: Could I just do `ServerName *.domain.com`?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh No, the wildcard must be in `ServerAlias`.

Answer (score 1):

The above uses **mod_vhost_alias**, I use **mod_rewrite**, something like this in the first defined (default) VirtualHost:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap lc int:tolower

RewriteCond /var/www/${lc:%{SERVER_NAME}} -f 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)   /var/www/${lc:%{SERVER_NAME}}/htdocs/$1
```

This lets you add a little more logic, should it be useful.
I had thought that another advantage of the mod_rewrite approach is that it would handle any domain, not necessarily sub-domains -- but on testing (httpd-2.2.x) it seems that `ServerAlias` will accept any reasonable * and ? wildcards, including *.com or even *. So, no win if you don't need the complexity.

In either case, it can be useful to use LogFormat/CustomLog directives to put the requested virtualhost name (`%v`) into the logs:

```
LogFormat   "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"   log-with-vhost
```

See also http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html for many of the mass-virtual-hosting tips.